# How to change XtraGrid Column PopUp Menu?

Tags: winforms, contextmenu, xtragrid

I have my own ContextMenu. I want to know that how can I disable Default Column Popup Menu for DevExpress XtraGrid control and show my own ContextMenu when user right-clicks on specified Column?

Comment: Can someone help up please. I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer to a similar question: [How to add to the GRidViewColumnMenu Color und Font Editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028338/how-to-add-to-the-gridviewcolumnmenu-color-und-font-editors/14859772#14859772)

All you need to change is clearing the default Items collection, and instead of adding a new DXEditMenuItem, add one of these: DXMenuItem, DXCheckItem, etc., use which you need. But the idea is quite the same.